# Ceph mounted rbd poor performance

Tags: performance, ceph

all tests are done from an external server connected with 10G to all 3 ceph nodes and  the cluster is all nvme flash.

when i ran fio with this config:

```
[global]
ioengine=rbd
clientname=admin
pool=kubernetes-prod
rbdname=image01
rw=write
bs=4m
direct=1
size=512M
runtime=30
time_based
[rbd_iodepth32]
iodepth=32
```

i get `write: IOPS=207, BW=830MiB/s (870MB/s)(24.4GiB/30114msec); 0 zone resets`

when i ran mount the rbd to the system and create an fs

```
rbd map image01 -p kubernetes-prod --name client.admin -m 10.0.0.60:6789,10.0.0.61:6789,10.0.0.62
/sbin/mkfs.ext4 -m0 /dev/rbd0
mount /dev/rbd0 /mnt/rbd
```

and run fio with this config i get

```
[global]
filename=/mnt/rbd/test.bin
rw=write
bs=4m
direct=1
size=512M
runtime=30
time_based
[rbd_iodepth32]
iodepth=32
```

i get `write: IOPS=64, BW=258MiB/s (271MB/s)(7756MiB/30011msec); 0 zone resets`

i also tried cephfs with the same poor performance. the goal is to use this in kubernetes with CSI but the performance is to poor and i don’t know why the mounted rbd is so much slower. CPU and RAM are not maxed out during the test.

when i ran `rbd bench` or `rados bench` the perfromance is even better

Comment: Check out the [ceph performance blog](https://ceph.io/en/news/blog/2023/reef-freeze-rbd-performance/) from the latest release (Reef). I didn't read it in detail, but maybe you find some hints for your setup. By the way, your 3 nodes have how many OSDs each?

Comment: i will look into this and update the post if i find anything. echo node has 2 osd so 6 in total.